# Get friend app user with graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get friend app user with Graph API 
 I tried to user with `me/friends?fields=installed` but I got all of my friends. Maybe, I have some wrong in here.
 Please show me any way to get friend app user with Graph API. I don't know in Facebook SDK 3.0 can I get that list easier?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacement for old GetAppUsers call to see a user's friends who use my app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7956639/replacement-for-old-getappusers-call-to-see-a-users-friends-who-use-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of friends whom are user of your app using **FQL** rather than Graph API as:

```
SELECT uid FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
AND is_app_user = 1
```