# Need Facebook API call to find friend using my app

Tags: java, javascript, json, facebook-graph-api, lwuit

I have made an app on Nokia S40 using Lwuit library. My app is also on Facebook and exists individually too. I need to get my Facebook friends who are using that app from Facebook. 
I know how vague this question is, but I need a script JSON query to be able to get them.
Unfortunately, I have no knowledge about Facebook API.

I know my App ID and access token.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924397/get-friend-app-user-with-graph-api should give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API never worked properly in LWUIT because of several inherent bugs in the HTMLComponent and OAuth code. We fixed all of those in Codename One but backporting this isn't practical.

I suggest checking out [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) and the facebook demo therein.